# When we using alert vs popup div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my opinion, show an popup by div tag will better. All my project i has been shown mgs box by div tag.

Example

```
$('#myMSG').html("Some error occure, please try again").show();
```

But now, when I changed to new company, I manage an 1 project from other person has been left. I see all msbox throw by alert.

Example:

```
alert( "Some error occure, please try again");
```

I think they have some reason for using alert.

My confused is: when we use alert, and when we use div tag to show msg for user,
advantage between them?

Comment: i would say "it depends" ... both are totally different. And you question is off-topic

Comment: I don't thing any comparision is there like advantages or disadvantages. Only thing is error in div can be stylish and placed anywhere on the page along with some sort of jquery animation applied too, but default alert doesn't. Even custome alert also possible which gave you styling opportunity. So it's completley based on your own choice

Comment: Well alert is ugly and blocking, because of its blocking nature you could say alert might be useful for debugging, but browsers have good debuggers nowadays.

Comment: A Good Boy  better to read comment and then remove your question because you are going to face many down-votes in near future.

Comment: it's actually an interesting question, what are the reasons for down voting this?

Comment: @abimelex interesting but off-topic

Comment: It's a special case regarding best practice in UX _but_ strongly code related, so I see why people might think it's off-topic. Giving a closer look to the issue it could be actually a common problem which would be interesting to see some best practice rules.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the main reason for using alert() is to have native support. In a web app I would use only alert, for desktop websites mostly div popup.

But actually the question would fit better in https://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks, i want delete but it warning:We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

Comment: @AGoodBoy you should have deleted when you were getting a mass of downvotes and before getting answers ... now the more you wait the more you make it difficult for you. By the way the question may soon get closed